# java: Store HashMap<String, String> in ArrayList<Object>

Tags: java, android, arraylist, hashmap

```
ArrayList<Object> parameters = new ArrayList<Object>();

HashMap<String, String> parameter = new HashMap<String, String>();
parameter.put("key", "value");

parameters.add(parameter);
parameters.add((String) "additionalData"); //this line is here for a reason
destinationFunction(parameters);

....

destinationFunction(ArrayList<Object> data){
     HashMap<String, String> imported = (HashMap<String, String>) data.get(0);
     String value = imported.get("key");
}
```

How do i achieve this? When i try i receive no errors up until like 2 of destinationFunction where i receive null pointer exception

Comment: try new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>(); definition

Comment: you can create arraylist of hashmaps

Comment: please post complete [logcat](https://politecuriosity.files.wordpress.com/2013/05/logcat.jpg).

Comment: would that prevent `parameters.add("additionalData");` as the ArrayList is now of a specific object?

Comment: @Simon. Yes It will. It won't let you add anything other than `HashMap<String, String>`

Comment: alternative solution would be to use JSON Objects and arrays.

Comment: @nafas if you put that into an answer i'll accept it for this question. your solution is the easiest, and closest to solving the exact question! just suing HashMap<String, String> was overkill in the long run. JSONObject was perfect! thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Alternative** Solution would be using `JsonObject` and `JsonArrays`.
they are perfect for such "scenarios" (working with String,Integer and etc with combination of List and Map).

they may also be useful for complex object(e.g. working with Images) but will be abit more difficult to implement. in such cases please refer to [java_serialization](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_serialization.htm)

in your case use `JSONArray` instead of your `ArrayList` and `JsonObject` instead of `HashMap`.

Comment: This solution solves the exact problem described in the question, where as implementing just an ArrayList of HashMap<String, String> would omit the single string value also contained in the ArrayList.

Answer (score 1):

```
ArrayList<Object> parameters = new ArrayList<Object>();
```

relpace this line with what you want to store in array list
like you want to store hash map then create arraylist of type hash map

```
 ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> parameters = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
```

hope this will help you

Answer (score 0):

use array list of hashmap

```
ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>()
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to put `ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>` instead of `ArrayList<Object>`

create a **HashMap** and add into the **ArrayList.**
**For Example:-**

```
ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> list = new ArrayList<>();

HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
map.put("KEY", "VALUE");

list.add(map); //Add the map into list
```

Answer (score 0):

You did not specified what type are you storing in your arrayList. But you assume in your `destinationFunction` that this list contains only `HashMap<String, String>` elements. Besides terrible code style it is okay in java to write so. But you made a mistake when put in your arrayList an element of type `String` which is breaking your assumptions in `destinationFunction`.

P.S. Try to write more type safe code and avoid generic types with `Object` type parameter.